# Grails application using grails-gradle-plugin gets PermGen space error upon run-app

Tags: grails, gradle

I have a multi-project gradle build that has several Grails app.
One of these app contains many artefacts (controllers, services, groovy code, etc...).

When I run it using the gradle grails-run-app command, I get the following error:

```
| Error Server failed to start: PermGen space (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

We tried to add to buildConfig.groovy the following

```
disable.auto.recompile=true
```

and add the following to the gradle.properties

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=1G -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled
```

But the error remain

I am using:
Grails 2.3.1, Gradle 1.8 and grails-gradle-plugin 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT

Any ideas ?

Eduardo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following lines to the begin of your gradle.build

```
import org.grails.gradle.plugin.GrailsTask

tasks.withType(org.grails.gradle.plugin.GrailsTask) { Task t ->
    t.jvmOptions {
        jvmArgs '-Xms32m -Xmx1524m -XX:PermSize=32m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseParNewGC'.split(' ')
    }
}
```

It runs every grails task with the specified jvm args.

Check this [link](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/outofmemory_in_grails_plugin)

Comment: Use import org.grails.gradle.plugin.tasks.GrailsTask for v2.1.0 of grails-gradle-plugin